# Differences on biological classification?

Tags: classification

Why we use the term phylum for kingdom animali but for kingdom planti ,fungi and prokaryota we use them division?                         What difference between phylum and division ?

Answer (score 2):

Phylum and division are both listed under the same [taxonomic ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank). The wikipedia page for phylum states that

> Traditionally, in botany the term division was used instead of
>   "phylum", although from 1993 the International Code of Nomenclature
>   for algae, fungi, and plants accepted the designation "phylum".

What you have to keep in mind is that the scientists categorizing plants and animals worked in isolation for a long time and only recently have they come together to build a tree of life for all organisms (rather than just working separately on plants / animals / bacteria)

Comment: Is it just for a tradition ???

Comment: probably for that and legacy purposes to not confuse the people already in the field